# Ajax request 303 redirect on a multilingual website

Tags: ajax, multilingual, jroute, security-token

I have an ajax task to return a form token from my controller for use in ajax pages, so that subsequent ajax requests will have a token. It looks like this in the code:

```
JURI::root().'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax.tokenRequest'
```

and like this in the ajax request:

```
http://localhost/joomla3/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax.tokenRequest
```

This works fine, until I use it in a multilingual site. In this case, the server returns a 303 error with the suggested redirect to

```
http://localhost/joomla3/en/?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax.tokenRequest
```

and the token never gets populated.

Is there something I need to do similar to `JRoute::_()` on the URL to ensure that the right URL is used and a 303 is not returned? (I did try JRoute but this didn't have any effect).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `JUri::root()` try to use this:

```
$baseUrl = JUri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port', 'path'));
$baseUrl .'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax.tokenRequest'
```

[See](https://compojoom.com/blog/entry/ajax-requests-on-multilingual-joomla-websites) the reference.

Or simply do not use `JUri::root()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be nice to use the JSession::getFormToken() method to increse the security of your AJAX request. [See also How to add CSRF anti-spoofing to forms](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

It is not very clear from your question, but it looks to me that you are not passing the language to the Request (like specifying the language parameter `lang=de`).

Also have a look into VirtualHosts for your development environment, so that you can have something like http://mycooljoomlasite.local instead of http://localhost/joomla3

Comment: I'm using the `JSession::getFormToken()` at the ajax endpoint to get the token. This is necessary because if you simply declare the variable in js (`var token = JSession etc`) it will be cached (if Joomla caching is on) and your token will always be invalid.

Comment: That is interesting. Did you test it?